# Why do forms ask to confirm email address?

Tags: forms, email

Why do most forms (mostly traditionally I believe) ask users to confirm their email address and have two fields of email address (one is called email address and second one is usually called 'Confirm email')? Most of the time this is done in registration or contact forms. Is it a way to filter out robots or is it database check and used only for certain DB types (MS SQL etc.). Or maybe developers want us to be 100% sure that the email address we input is correct that by getting us to input it twice we can check over it is actually correct (and correct in two places?).

Sounds like a silly question by why do developers do it instead of asking for the email address once?

For all I know is that if we can check the email in one form field against the DB entry then this is sufficient and build security in another way.

Comment: The is always a possiblity of typo errors while filling in the details in any form fields. There is a lesser chance of making error twice. If the values are not same the user can be alerted. This is normally done in email and password field. Entering wrong information by mistake will make the account unusable.

Comment: This is what I wanted to poke at. It is true that the chance of entering a wrong email is lessened if the same email is entered twice and it's good the user can be alerted. Also I wonder if there is any other way to do it instead of asking it twice. I myself have made some accounts unusable on some websites but I can't remember the combination of incorrect info I inputted to reach there.

Comment: Since the value we want to verify is not stored anywhere, the easiest way to confirm is by making the user enter twice. I'm not sure whether there is any other better way. Sorry

Comment: This works only if the user uses keyboard. I've seen cases where the first textbox is filled using keyboard and user copies the first textbox value using mouse and paste it in second textbox in a hurry. If the first textbox value is wrong, the whole point of having two boxes is useless. So it is also good to block copy paste in similar textboxes.

Comment: This question is blatantly off-topic, and should be closed.

Answer (score 2):

**As you mentioned, It is done to be 100% sure.**
It is done because developers want the user to review that the email address they have given is correct as a confirmation mail would be sent to that email and if the email is wrong then if would lead to a spam mail sent and at the same time the user may not complete the whole login procedure again.

Comment: Mostly for TYPOS...Its only for confirmation and ensuring you enter the correct email address. I guess sites that transact serious/confidential customer data would like their users to be sure that there are no TYPOS while entering their email address. People could enter, johnd.oe@gmail.com instead of john.doe@gmail. And for gmail, they are two different people.

Comment: Thanks Ankit. So we are catering for users who could make a mistake? Do we have to? Why not let them make the mistake and in out DB not accept it. For instance if it's a company or shop where have purchased something from and this is what they have to do in the contact form we know their email address won't reach them. So they may end up calling the company and ask about their query only to be told you probably entered the wrong email address if they get asked this. I don't think a wrong email address will cause spam if our DB doesn't accept it in the first place.

Comment: @ParttimeCoder you can only check if the email is correct if you have it already in your database, and it you already have the email then why would you ask for email?

Comment: Yes bbh, true in regards to the gmail issue. I guess we could warn users to be 'very sure your email' is correct before hitting submit. Maybe Banks do this but I can't remember when I registered if I had to confirm my email address. Also true that we all make typos.

Comment: It all depends on the requirement of the website or product. If the business does not want to lose a customer just becuse they entered the wrong email and the whole account opening got messed up, they would prefer to have additional check. As I mentioned, it all depends.

Answer (score 0):

It is important in order to avoid typographical errors.

Comment: Yes - But I think I have to keep in context then and only talk about forms as it's too generic to bring in other form types. So do you think there is any other way of avoiding the typos without asking the users to input two email addresses?

Comment: For example in web forms: I'm using chromium and it saves my mail by default. If Chromium detects that I'm filling a mail field then it writes my mail and I don't need to type anything. It's the most comfortable way for me and it avoids typos, but maybe it's not very safe and it depends of the client browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is a well-meaning but ultimately misguided attempt to prevent people from accidentally typing their email address incorrectly.

It's misguided because it forces **every single user** to waste an extra 10 to 20 seconds re-typing their email address in order to catch a very small number of typos. It is extremely inefficient and shows a complete lack of respect for users' time. It puts a burden on all users for the sole benefit of the service provider who wants to ensure clean data. It's a classic "externality" in an economic sense.

UX/UI and web developers must always remember that any inefficiencies that we (deliberately or inadvertently) design into an interface are multiplied by how often that interface is used. You might think it's only an extra 10 seconds to ask someone to retype an email address, but if you have 100K new users a month, you're wasting 3,300 hours of human productivity each year just to prevent a few typos, which can easily be handled through other methods (email syntax validation and sending an authentication code to the email address that is entered).

What boggles the mind is when forms are developed to disable copy/paste on the "confirmation" field. If you're going to go through that much trouble, just send the user a confirmation link to ensure they typed the correct email address.

In short, "Please re-enter your email address" is a lazy design that wastes peoples' time and provides no benefit that can't be realized by other means that also respects users' time.